# Deleting schema extensions which have are not in the InDevelopment state

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Per the documentation you can only delete schema extensions which are *InDevelopment*. Once a schema has moved to *Available*, there is no path back to *InDevelopment*.

Is there really no way to remove a schema you have made available? Or is it available on the beta endpoint, or planned for the future?

In my tenants I also see lots of dummy/test schema extensions, and it would be nice to clean them up - and I cannot really see which application created/owns the schema.

If I cannot really control and own schema extensions in my tenant, the functionality look less appealing than it initially did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a limitation of Graph but rather a well established behavior of Active Directory from the beginning.

Rather than "deleting", Active Directory uses a [deactivation model](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961741.aspx). Microsoft Graph uses the state "[Deprecated](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions-lifecycle)" to denote an deactivated schema extension. So while you can't [Delete](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_delete) it, you can [Update](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_update) it and set the state to `deprecated`.

There is an interesting article on this topic from 2002 that you might find interesting: [Your Mission: Delete from the AD Schema](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/your-mission-delete-ad-schema). *Please note that I cannot condone or support his methods for getting around the lack of schema deletion. Going at AD in this manner is almost assuredly going to carry numerous unforeseen and nasty implications. I only provide the link for your edification and highlight how long this limitation has been in place.*

Comment: I realise AAD is what drives this, but lack of full control makes schema extensions less appealing in my opinion. I cannot fully test when the schema is InDevelopment as I cannot use it with objects, and once I make it active, I loose ability to delete properties, only add them. The benefit for me with schema extensions is the ability to filter, but I'll probably end up using open extensions and filter with custom code instead - looping over all objects. And I'll add caching or similar to make up for speed. That or store extra data somewhere flexible and fast.

Comment: I agree and highly recommend standing up a separate developer AD for this very reason.

Comment: Good idea on a dev AD. Would I also need a separate tenant to make this work, as I want to use the schema on O365 artifacts. Right now I'm using my dev tenant, but I don't want to clutter this one up too much either. Maybe a 30 day trial is the way to go when working with this.

Comment: I've often used 30-day trials when I'm in the "throwing bits at the wall" stage. Since O365 leverages AAD behind the scenes you get both spun up pretty quickly. It's also a good excuse to take the time and script any production schema/configuration changes so you can quickly re-apply them to a new scratch tenant. :)

Comment: Sounds like a smart approach..except the scripting part where I prefer app tokens. But I'll figure something out over the weekend :) But I'm not overly enthused about how this works from a management perspective, not allowing deletes..but it is what it is.

Comment: Mikael - I'd like to dig deeper to see if we can make some improvements to the lifecycle.  I'll also provide some reasons why we have the lifecycle as we currently do - but maybe there's an improvement opportunity here.  Question:  can you provide more details on what you could not do while your schema was "inDevelopment"?  FYI the schema lifecycle is documented here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions

Answer (score 2):

Some background on the decisions we made around schema lifecycle that hopefully will answer some of your questions.  The schema lifecycle is documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions)

Summary:

- While the schema is `inDevelopment` you can make additive changes and also delete the schema.  There are limitations as to what can be done, but within that scope it should be fully functional.  (Scope here is that, in this state, only the owner app can extend resource instances with this schema definition, and only in the same directory where the owner app is registered. )
- Additive changes only - well we did that because if you remove any properties from the schema definition, you'll end up with a breaking change for any resource instances that have been extended by this schema.
- Why deprecate - why can't I delete my `Available` schema definition?  So we did this because if you delete a schema definition, this would lead to a data loss situation - as well as breaking any others that depend on this schema extension, because there would be no way for us to reason about an extension to a resource instance, based on a deleted definition. Essentially the `Deprecated` state allows it to be hidden from everyone apart from the app owner, but still there so that there are no data loss situations.

If there are improvements to the lifecycle model, we're certainly very open to those.

Anyway hope this helps,

Comment: It makes sense as per data loss, but we could argue this :) I still find it odd that my tenants have lots of seemingly dummy schemes in them - assumably created by Microsoft. I'll pull out the ownerid's and try to correlate which apps own them.

Comment: My issue with InDevelopment might be solved now with your fix if I can use the same ADAL app with delegated perm to create the schema as I use with app tokens for resource extension. Meaning, I won't use Graph Explorer to create the schema.